# Chernoff Type Bounds for a Stopped Sum of Independent Random Variables

Tags: stopping-times, concentration-of-measure

Let $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ and $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d. $p$-Bernoulli random variables and let $T \in \{0, \ldots, n\}$ be a [stopping time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time) for the process. From [Wald's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation), we know
$$
E\left[\sum_{i=1}^T Y_i \right] = E\left[\sum_{i=1}^T X_i \right] = p \times E[T].
$$
On the other hand, if $T$ was not itself a random variable, a standard Chernoff bound would give that for $\mu = pT$ and any $0 < \delta < 1$, with probability $\geq 1-\exp(-\delta^2 \mu/3)$ we have
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^T Y_i \in (1\pm \delta) \sum_{i=1}^T X_i.
$$
Now going back to $T$ being a stopping time and not known a priori, can we get a similar concentration bound? That is, letting $\mu$ be a given lower bound for the expected value of $\sum_{i=1}^T X_i$, does the statement above still hold?

**Note**: One could try to apply Chernoff bound over all $n$ choices of $T$ and set the failure probability small enough that with high probability, no matter the value of $T$, sum of the two sequences are close up to any point. Unfortunately, though, to be able to do this, the error probability would have to depend on $n$ whereas the original bound is dimension-free. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: this needs re-written.... "*...a standard Chernoff bound would give that for $\mu = pT$ and any $0 < \delta < 1$, with probability $\geq 1-\exp(-\delta^2 \mu/3)$ we have*
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^T Y_i = (1\pm \delta) \sum_{i=1}^T X_i.
$$"  But this is impossible.  The LHS is integer valued WP1 and the RHS is never integer valued except in the special case of all 'tails' which occurs with probability $(1-p)^t$.  *"Now going back to $T$ being a stopping time and not a random variable... "*   what does this mean?  $T$ is a defective r.v.?  What else could it be?

Comment: I updated the question. The equality was supposed to be $\in$, i.e. within $(1 \pm \delta)$ factor of the other sum. About the second question, there are two scenarios, (1) when $T$ is a stopping time (that is, $T$ itself is a random variable), or when (2) $T$ is known a-priori. Chernoff bounds work for the latter, my question is to extend it to the former.

Comment: This question was answered on mathoverflow. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354145/chernoff-type-bounds-for-a-stopped-sum-of-independent-random-variables).